# "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." in SWTableViewCell for Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin

I am porting SWTableCell ([GitHub](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell)) to Xamarin.iOS. I already implemented all code in C#, but I still have a problem with constraints.

I am getting this message:

```
2014-06-23 11:58:59.004 Mark5MobileiOS[1423:70b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xe5cd1b0 UIView:0xe5cc310.right == DocumentListViewCell:0xe5c2280.right>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xe5cc370 H:[DocumentListViewCell:0xe5c2280]-(820)-[UIView:0xe5cc310] (LTR)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xe5cc370 H:[DocumentListViewCell:0xe5c2280]-(820)-[UIView:0xe5cc310](LTR)>
```

I think I have found constraints that cause this error, but I have to put a larger piece of code so that it makes sense.

```
    protected void Initialize ()
    {
        _cellScrollView = new SwipeableScrollView ();
        _cellScrollView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        _cellScrollView.Delegate = new SwipeableScrollViewDelegate (this);
        _cellScrollView.ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
        _cellScrollView.ScrollsToTop = false;
        _cellScrollView.ScrollEnabled = true;
        AddSubview (_cellScrollView);

        AddConstraints (new[] {
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create (_cellScrollView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1.0f, 0.0f),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create (_cellScrollView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1.0f, 0.0f),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create (_cellScrollView, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1.0f, 0.0f),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create (_cellScrollView, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1.0f, 0.0f)
        });

        _cellContentView = new UIView ();
        _cellContentView.AddSubview (ContentView);
        _cellScrollView.AddSubview (_cellContentView);

        TapGestureRecognizer = new UITapGestureRecognizer (HandleScrollViewTapped);
        TapGestureRecognizer.CancelsTouchesInView = false;

        _longPressGestureRecognizer = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer (HandleScrollViewLongPressed);
        _longPressGestureRecognizer.CancelsTouchesInView = false;
        _longPressGestureRecognizer.MinimumPressDuration = 0.2f;

        TapGestureRecognizer.Delegate = new SwipeableCellGestureRecognizerDelegate (this, _longPressGestureRecognizer);
        _longPressGestureRecognizer.Delegate = new SwipeableCellGestureRecognizerDelegate (this, _longPressGestureRecognizer);

        _cellScrollView.AddGestureRecognizer (TapGestureRecognizer);
        _cellScrollView.AddGestureRecognizer (_longPressGestureRecognizer);

        // Create the left and right utility button views, as well as vanilla UIViews in which to embed them.  We can manipulate the latter in order to effect clipping according to scroll position.
        // Such an approach is necessary in order for the utility views to sit on top to get taps, as well as allow the backgroundColor (and private UITableViewCellBackgroundView) to work properly.

        _leftUtillityClipView = new UIView ();
        _leftUtillityClipViewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create (_leftUtillityClipView, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        _leftUtilityButtonsView = new SwipeableUtilityButtonView (_leftUtilityButtons, this, HandleUtilityButtonPressed);

        _rightUtilityClipView = new UIView ();
        _rightUtilityClipViewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create (_rightUtilityClipView, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        _rightUtilityButtonsView = new SwipeableUtilityButtonView (_rightUtilityButtons, this, HandleUtilityButtonPressed);

        // Perform common configuration on both sets of utility items (left and right).

        var clipViews = new [] { _leftUtillityClipView, _rightUtilityClipView };
        var clipConstraints = new [] { _leftUtillityClipViewConstraint, _rightUtilityClipViewConstraint };
        var buttonViews = new [] { _leftUtilityButtonsView, _rightUtilityButtonsView };
        var alignmentAttributes = new [] { NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutAttribute.Right };

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            var clipView = clipViews [i];
            var clipConstraint = clipConstraints [i];
            var buttonView = buttonViews [i];
            var alignmentAttribute = alignmentAttributes [i];

            clipView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
            clipView.ClipsToBounds = true;

            AddSubview (clipView);
            AddConstraints (new [] {
                // Pin the clipping view to the appropriate outer edges of the cell.
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create (clipView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1.0f, 0.0f),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create (clipView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1.0f, 0.0f),
/* THIS LINE */         NSLayoutConstraint.Create (clipView, alignmentAttribute, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, this, alignmentAttribute, 1.0f, 0.0f),
/* OR THIS LINE */          clipConstraint,
            });

            clipView.AddSubview (buttonView);
            AddConstraints (new [] {
                // Pin the button view to the appropriate outer edges of its clipping view.
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create (buttonView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, clipView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1.0f, 0.0f),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create (buttonView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, clipView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1.0f, 0.0f),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create (buttonView, alignmentAttribute, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, clipView, alignmentAttribute, 1.0f, 0.0f),
                // Constrain the maximum button width so that at least a button's worth of contentView is left visible. (The button view will shrink accordingly.)
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create (buttonView, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.LessThanOrEqual, ContentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1.0f, -SwipeableUtilityButtonView.UtilityButtonWidthDefault)
            });
        }
    }
```

When I remove one of the marked lines the message disappears, but code does not work properly.
You can find the original implementation here [SWTableViewCell.m](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell/blob/master/SWTableViewCell/PodFiles/SWTableViewCell.m#L146-L147) - lines 146 and 147.

I tried to translate the code as well as I could and not change the implementation so that I do not get errors like these, but as you can see I failed.

I am really surprised because to me, my implementation and the original implementation looks exactly the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Once I finish and test my version of SWTableViewCell I will put it on GitHub so others don't have to waste time on this ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have found bug in another piece of code, so the snippet above is correct.